# How to match SSH config based on URL path or SSH arguments (for github deploy keys)?

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to use multiple deploy keys for github, which means I need to match my SSH configs based on the repository name. I cannot match based on hostname, port or user because they are all the same. Only repo name and deploy keys are different.

I know this question has been asked before but I can't find a satisfactory answer because I am not interested in adding a subdomain or user to my github ssh URL. This question is specifically on how to match a URL PATH or SSH argument or other workaround that do not involve modifying the default github ssh URL.

The default ssh github url is `git@github.com:githubusername/githubreponame.git`

The usual SSH configs are:

```
# repo 1
# MATCH or HOST xxxxxxxxxxx
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myrepo1name_rsa

# repo 2
# MATCH or HOST xxxxxxxxxxx
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myrepo2name_rsa
```

As per the ssh config manual http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html you can use 2 parameters to match a config, HOST or MATCH.

We already know that HOST cannot do it. So MATCH is the only way:

> The available criteria keywords for MATCH are:
>                canonical, final, exec, host, originalhost, user, and
>                localuser.

From those MATCH criteria keywords, it seems none of them have access to the repo name or the SSH arguments or anything useful.

The MATCH `exec` criteria keyword seems promising:

> The exec keyword executes the specified command under the
>                user's shell.  If the command returns a zero exit status then
>                the condition is considered true.

`exec` has access to the following variables http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html#TOKENS:

```
%h    The remote hostname.
%i    The local user ID.
%L    The local hostname.
%l    The local hostname, including the domain name.
%n    The original remote hostname, as given on the command line.
%p    The remote port.
%r    The remote username.
%u    The local username.
```

None of these variables appear useful to me.

I have tried the following:

```
Match exec "pwd | grep myreponame1"
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myreponame1_rsa
```

It is partly successful, as usually when I am using git I am inside the repo directory so `pwd | grep reponame` will exit true. But it doesn't work for cloning or if I use a different directory name.

I am looking for a better alternative, which would probably also use `MATCH exec` in some way.

Edit: the best solution I found so far is:

```
Match exec "git remote get-url origin | grep reponame || echo $REPO | grep reponame"
```

But I'm not 100% happy with it because I need to add an env variable before git clone.

Answer (score 33):

You can specify an SSH key for a particular GitHub user or a repository.

Change a hostname with `url` rule in the global git config. Then select the correct identity for the hostname with `Host` rule in the SSH agent config.

**Example**:

GitHub username: `user1`.

Repository: `git@github.com:user1/repo.git`.

User identity file: `~/.ssh/id_rsa_user1`.

`~/.gitconfig` or `~/.config/git/config`:

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
[url "git@github-user1:user1"]
    insteadOf = git@github.com:user1
```

`~/.ssh/config`:

```
AddKeysToAgent  yes
IdentitiesOnly yes

Host github-user1
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_user1

Host *.example.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_example
```

Git will substitute `git@github.com:user1` with `git@github-user1:user1`. So the new hostname will be `github-user1`. Then the SSH agent will use the new hostname to select the `user1` identity file `~/.ssh/id_rsa_user1`.

Now you can clone the repository with the following command:

```
git clone git@github.com:user1/repo.git
```

**Notes**:

Only one `url` rule is applied. So this will not work:

```
git clone https://github.com/user1/repo.git
```

SSH config manual:

```
man ssh_config
```

Parameters meanings:

- `AddKeysToAgent` - store a key and its passphrase in the agent on first use.
- `IdentitiesOnly` - only use configured identities even if the agent has more identities.

Default identity is `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. If you use it do not set it via top level `IdentityFile` or `Host *` rule or you will experience the following problem:

- The default identity is set with `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa`.
- The default identity is in the agent and `id_rsa_user1` is not.
- The agent will use the default identity for `github-user1` host, despite `Host github-user1` rule.

Comment: BTW, the same works for gitlab as well.

Comment: How can we add a different [user] name and email for each `[url "..."]`?

Answer (score 14):

The simplest thing to do is to create separate alias for each respository.

```
Host repo1
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myrepo1name_rsa

Host repo2
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myrepo2name_rsa
```

Then use `repo1:githubusername/githubreponame.git` and `repo2:githubusername/githubreponame.git` as the URLS in Git.

To make it less repetitive, you can define aliases with a pattern you can match on.

```
Host gitrepo1
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myrepo1name_rsa

Host gitrepo2
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myrepo2name_rsa

Host git*
  HostName github.com
  User git
```

Comment: I've seen this solution already during my research, and it works, but I'm looking specifically a solution that wouldn't require me editing the git ssh url

Comment: `ssh` doesn't care about the rest of the path. Git is what uses the path after the `ssh` connection is established.

Comment: sure I get that, but since `MATCH exec` allows you to execute arbitrary code, I bet there is some way to know which path git will use, or some other workaround

Comment: It can execute arbitrary code, but you need someway to get the path *to* that code. You might be able to define a custom transport helper (see `man gitremote-helpers`) to work with a path transformed by a wrapper around the `git` command.

Comment: that's a good idea. `MATCH exec "git remote get-url origin | grep reponame"` works. But I can't use it for git clone. I tried `MATCH exec "git remote get-url origin | grep reponame || history 2 | grep -E 'clone.+reponame'"` but that failed.

Comment: This is the right way, the github way. [Using multiple repositories on one server](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#using-multiple-repositories-on-one-server)

Answer (score 4):

Here's pretty much what I do:

```
Host github.com gist.github.com
  Hostname %h
  User git
  RequestTTY no
  RemoteCommand none
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  ControlMaster no

Match host github.com,gist.github.com exec "~/Developer/C++/getargv/getargv -0 -s 1 $PPID | env POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 xargs -0 getopt '46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYyB:b:c:D:E:e:F:I:i:J:L:l:m:O:o:p:Q:R:S:W:w:' | perl -pe 's|.*? -- ||' | fgrep -e username1"
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keys/github_rsa

Match host github.com,gist.github.com exec "~/Developer/C++/getargv/getargv -0 -s 1 $PPID | env POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 xargs -0 getopt '46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYyB:b:c:D:E:e:F:I:i:J:L:l:m:O:o:p:Q:R:S:W:w:' | perl -pe 's|.*? -- ||' | fgrep -e username2"
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keys/github_rsa2
```

I set the common github configs in the top `Host` block, then each `Match` block looks at the arguments passed to ssh, parses them, and checks for the github username and if it matches, sets the correct key.

The `~/Developer/C++/getargv/getargv` program is just an implementation of `cat /proc/$PPID/cmdline` for macOS, on linux you don't need a separate tool.

This works for cloning, pushing, pulling, etc.

Comment: Great idea. In Linux I've been able to use something like `Match exec "grep reponame /proc/$PPID/cmdline"` to use a specific key for each repo. Of course this is a bit naive as `grep` treats `cmdline` as binary because of the argument separator is `NUL`, but of course it works nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a domain name then **you can hack this**.

Let's say your domain is `mydomain.com`.

##### Use your domain instead of github.com in your ssh config:

In `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host repo1.github.mydomain.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/repo1_key
Host repo2.github.mydomain.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/repo2_key
```

##### Use your domain instead of github.com in your repo url:

In `repo1/.git/config`

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@repo1.github.mydomain.com:username/repo1.git
```

In `repo2/.git/config`

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@repo2.github.mydomain.com:username/repo2.git
```

##### Add CNAME record to github.com

Add a wildcard CNAME record `*.github.mydomain.com` and point to `github.com`,so no need to add one by one afterwards.

##### What if I don't have a domain? Use `/etc/hosts`

You can't use wildcard in `/etc/hosts`, so you have to add an alias for each repo. Good thing is you can use whatever hostname you want.

```
ip_of_github  a.repo b.repo c.repo
```

Then use these hostnames in your `~/.ssh/config` and `.git/config`s

That's it.